# Just a noob question ! How to add my custom token the list of "show all token" list on MEW . Just like a this

Tags: tokens, erc-20, myetherwallet

[image]

I know it should need something qualified to do it . I just want to find a way do that .  Appreciate it if anyone could give me a help or instruction !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your token as a custom token by clicking the "Add Custom Token" button, and following the instructions, [here](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/send/adding-new-token-and-sending-custom-tokens.html).

If you want to see your token in the list of default tokens, you'll need to ask them to add it by raising a PR on GitHub (against `ethereum-lists`), [here](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/).

You might also want to raise a PR against the new "Ethereum Lists" project, [here](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/tokens).

Comment: Thx. Totally helpful .